# Ninject InRequestScope with asp.net web api delegating handler

Tags: ninject

I am using ninject with asp.net web api. I have bind all the interfaces with their implementation and all with **InRequestScope**.

Everything works fine in the controller and onwards, however, if i am trying to inject dependency in a delegating handler then the whole InRequestScope starts to fail.

I am seeing the behaviour that the Dispose method gets called after a few requests had gone by. The constructor also only been called on the first request.

**Resolved**
it was by design, the delegation handler is not been instantiated by the di container.